# Quicker way to go through nested if loop in awk rather than shell

Tags: shell, if-statement, awk, nested

I have following code

```
if [[ $intron_exon =~  E ]] ; then 
  upstream=$exon_id":I"$upstream_no
  downstream=$exon_id":I"$exon_number
    #nested in above if condition
    if grep -q -e "$upstream" Transcriptome.txt   ; then
     Up=$upstream
    fi
    #nested in above if condition
    if grep -q -e  "$downstream" Transcriptome.txt  ; then
     Down=$downstream
   fi
else 
  upstream=$exon_id":E"$upstream_no
  downstream=$exon_id":E"$exon_number
   #nested in above else condition
   if grep -q -e "$upstream" Transcriptome.txt  ; then
    Up=$upstream
   fi
   #nested in above else condition
   if  grep -q -e "$downstream" Transcriptome.txt  ; then
    Down=$downstream
   fi
fi
```

What I am trying to do is check if the variable is equal to E, if so then check if the upstream and downstream are present (Note that I initialize upstream and downstream differently in the main if and else); if not E then I initialize upstream and downstream differently and check if they are present in the file.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You are trying to optimize this working code? You speak of a nested loop, but I see no loop here. I'm unsure how awk would be utilized here except maybe to replace grep, but that seems silly.

Comment: See [ask] if you have a question.

Comment: I see four loops, but none nested. More like unnecessarily repeated. I think the question could be clearer, but if the question were much more clear, the OP may have already understood the problem enough to fix it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to refactor, you could write

```
[[ $intron_exon == *E* ]] && key=I || key=E

upstream=$exon_id:$key$upstream_no
grep -q -F "$upstream" Transcriptome.txt && Up=$upstream || Up="default up"

downstream=$exon_id:$key$exon_number
grep -q -F "$downstream" Transcriptome.txt && Down=$downstream || Down="default down"
```

I assume you want fixed string matching for grep.

Answer (score 1):

How big is `Transcriptome.txt`? That looks like your major bottleneck. Secondarily, you're repeating yourself.

If we simplify just a bit, we get:

```
if [[ $intron_exon =~ E ]]; then
  upstream=$exon_id":I"$upstream_no
  downstream=$exon_id":I"$exon_number
else
  upstream=$exon_id":E"$upstream_no
  downstream=$exon_id":E"$upstream_no
fi
# greps go here.
```

So now that we've refactored, if we can speed this up, we only have to do it once.  (You can refactor the above even more since the only difference is I vs E, so you can just use another variable for that.)

One trick here is then to use `awk` to print out your Up and Down assignments and then execute that, e.g.:

```
eval $(awk ...)
```

So now the trick is to get awk to loop through and print out the desired code on match. Something like this may suffice:

```
awk -e "/$upstream/{print \"Up=$upstream;\"} /$downstream/{print \"Down=$downstream;\"}" Transcriptome.txt
```

This will end up printing multiple `Up`s and `Down`s but the end result doesn't actually matter.

The downside is that this will read the entire file even if you have found the up and down fields early.

(There probably is a way to get awk to terminate early once both are found, but you'll have to determine if that's worth it.)

Putting it together, we get:

```
if [[ $intron_exon =~ E ]]; then
  upstream=$exon_id":I"$upstream_no
  downstream=$exon_id":I"$exon_number
else
  upstream=$exon_id":E"$upstream_no
  downstream=$exon_id":E"$upstream_no
fi
eval $(awk -e "/$upstream/{print \"Up=$upstream;\"} /$downstream/{print \"Down=$downstream;\"}" Transcriptome.txt)
```

Comment: I am checking if the $upstream and $downstream variable are present by if grep -q -e "$upstream" Transcriptome.txt and  grep -q -e "$downstream" Transcriptome.txt statements

Comment: @AishwaryaKulkarni, and that's what the above code does, too, just faster if the desired text is often not found.

Comment: Gotcha, it's just that from above gawk code I am trying to assign the Down and Up variables and export them to my main shell script, and for that I am trying to do something likegawk "/$upstream/{"Up=$upstream"} /$downstream/{"Down=$downstream"}" ../../Transcriptome.txt and I am getting a syntax error. I am doing something wrong in there

Comment: You think wrong. Google ["eval evil shell"](https://www.google.com/search?q=eval+evil+shell&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1)

Answer (score 1):

This MAY be what you're looking for:

```
awk -v intron_exon="$intron_exon" \
    -v exon_id="$exon_id" \
    -v upstream_no="$upstream_no" \
    -v exon_number="$exon_number" '
BEGIN {
    pfx = (intron_exon ~ /E/ ? ":I" : ":E")
    upstream   = exon_id pfx upstream_no
    downstream = exon_id pfx exon_number
}
$0 ~ upstream   { gotUp = 1 }
$0 ~ downstream { gotDn = 1 }
gotUp && gotDn  { exit      }
END {
    print (gotUp ? upstream   : "some_default_value")
    print (gotDn ? downstream : "some_default_value")
}
' file
```

It really depends what the rest of your script is doing.